# Boost c++ library install

Tags: c++, boost

I am not familiar with the usual build technique in linux I am using boost c++ library. Can any body guide me in installing and configuring boost c++ library. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you installing it? Which Linux distribution?

Answer (score 55):

My environment is Linux Fedora 15. On it, one can easily install boost by typing,

```
$ yum install boost-devel
```

After installation, you'll find boost under `/usr/include/boost/`.

However, if you run,

```
$yum install boost
```

you'll only find .so of boost under `/usr/lib/`, like `/usr/lib/libboost_timer.so.1.48.0`.

Answer (score 14):

It's OK if you're not familiar with the usual build technique because Boost doesn't use the usual build technique. Follow the instructions in the ["getting started" documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/index.html). Make sure you read all the way to the bottom of the page. The link to [the Unix-specific instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) is at the very, very bottom.

For most parts of Boost, installation is synonymous with unpacking the tarball into your preferred include directory. Other parts of Boost require compilation, so go to the Boost installation directory, run `./bootstrap.sh`, and then run `./bjam install`.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Kennedy's answer is still valid except that is [recommended](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/master/index.html) now to install with ./b2 instead of ./bjam.

Answer (score 2):

depending on the Linux distribution you are using, you'll probably find boost is already built and packaged for you, e.g. on Fedora "yum install boost"

Comment: i am using windows not linux system

Comment: @Chris, "yum install boost" completes fine on Fedora 16 but I am still not finding any split.hpp file! Also, the total download size is just 22k!!! What could be wrong?

Comment: Depending on what version you use, it is likely that split is not supported on whatever version you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Since fedora people are accumulating here. I drop my working solution for fedora 36.

using `dnf`

```
sudo dnf install boost-devel
```

Most parts of boost was working with that. I had some issues finding `boost_python`. So, I decided to compile it myself. Find other boost releases [here](https://www.boost.org/users/history/).

```
wget https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.78.0/source/boost_1_78_0.tar.gz
tar xvf ./boost_1_78_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_78_0
./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 --layout=versioned --build-type=complete address-model=64 install -j 16
```