# Build thread boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to follow the build manual and build the boost thread library in linux.
However, I found there is no lib folder and no library is shown after executing bootstrap.sh --show-libraries.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost c++ library install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278881/boost-c-library-install)

Answer (score 3):

```
bootstrap.sh
```

and only *then* do

```
b2 --show-libraries
```

Comment: @dophine: If you executed the above two command and had no output for the second, then something is really wrong. Unfortunately I cannot troubleshoot further.