# pyconfig.h not found while compiling Boost

Tags: python, boost

I am having been struggling with the Boost C++ libraries and Python. I have up to this point been completely unable to build the boost-python libraries.

The steps that I follow are:

- Download and unzip boost (currently trying to install 1.55.0, because 1.59.0 also did not want to work)
- Inside the boost_1_55_0 folder
- I type `./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python --prefix=/home/username/boost_prefix/`
- Then I type `./b2`
- When the compiler gets to the parts containing python I seem to get many errors looking like:

  > compilation terminated.
  >
  > "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/errors.o"
  >   "libs/python/src/errors.cpp"
  >
  > ...failed gcc.compile.c++
  >   bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/errors.o...
  >   gcc.compile.c++
  >   bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/module.o In
  >   file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
  >                    from ./boost/python/scope.hpp:8,
  >                    from libs/python/src/module.cpp:9: ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h:
  >   No such file or directory  # include
  >
  > ```
  >                    ^
  > ```
  >
  > compilation terminated.

Initially I thought that this is okay, because the documentation on boost says that you have to build the python part separately. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#id28)

So I follow the instructions

```
username$ cd libs/python/example/quickstart/
username$ ../../../../bjam toolset=gcc --verbose-test test
```

If left to complete the test example does not work and during compilation the output is very similar to the output above:

> Performing configuration checks
>
> ```
> - 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
> - 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
> - arm                      : no  (cached)
> - mips1                    : no  (cached)
> - power                    : no  (cached)
> - sparc                    : no  (cached)
> - x86                      : yes (cached)
> - symlinks supported       : yes (cached) ...patience... ...patience... ...found 1938 targets... ...updating 37 targets...
> ```
>
> gcc.compile.c++ bin/gcc-4.8.3/debug/extending.o In file included from
>   ../../../../boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
>                    from ../../../../boost/python/class.hpp:8,
>                    from extending.cpp:5: ../../../../boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error:
>   pyconfig.h: No such file or directory  # include 
>                          ^ compilation terminated.
>
> ```
> "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -fPIC    -I"../../../.." -I"/usr/include/python2.7" -c -o "bin/gcc-4.8.3/debug/extending.o" "extending.cpp"
> ```
>
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin/gcc-4.8.3/debug/extending.o...
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/debug/numeric.o In file
>   included from ../../../../boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
>                    from ../../../../boost/python/numeric.hpp:8,
>                    from ../../../../libs/python/src/numeric.cpp:6: ../../../../boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error:
>   pyconfig.h: No such file or directory  # include 
>                          ^ compilation terminated.
>
> ```
> "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -fPIC -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE  -I"../../../.." -I"/usr/include/python2.7" -c -o "../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/debug/numeric.o"
> ```
>
> "../../../../libs/python/src/numeric.cpp"
>
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++
>   ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/debug/numeric.o...
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.8.3/debug/list.o In file
>   included from ../../../../boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
>                    from ../../../../boost/python/list.hpp:8,
>                    from ../../../../libs/python/src/list.cpp:5: ../../../../boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error:
>   pyconfig.h: No such file or directory  # include 
>                          ^ compilation terminated.

I am running Centos 7 on a clean install on a 64bit system. I would appreciate any help so much!

Comment: Did you install `python-devel`?

Comment: Can you use 'sudo yum install boost' for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278881/boost-c-library-install